# Ember.js Not Updating DOM with Observed Value

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've got an Ember.js app with this javascript:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: false,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: false,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: false,
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('messageviewer', { path: '/message_viewer' });
});

App.Message = Ember.Object.extend({
    message: {},
    topic: '',
});
App.Message.reopenClass({
    messages: {},
    topics: [],

    getAllMessagesList: function(){
        var ret = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.topics.length; i++){
            ret = ret.concat(this.messages[this.topics[i]]);
        }
        return ret;
    }.observes('App.Message.messages');

    addMessage: function(message){
        console.log(message);
        if(!(message.topic in this.topics)){
            this.topics.push(message.topic);
            this.messages[message.topic] = [];
        }
        this.messages[message.topic].push(App.Message.create({
            message: message,
            topic: message.topic,
        }));
    },
});

App.MessageviewerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Message.getAllMessagesList();
    },
});

App.MessageviewerView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'messageViewer',
    didInsertElement: function(){
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, fayeStartListening);
    },
    willDestroyElement: function(){
        fayeStopListening();
    },
});
```

Here's the template that goes with the view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="filter-panel" class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Topics</h2>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical full-width" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="topics">Test 1</input>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="topics">Test 2</input>
            </label>
        </div>

        {{#with content}}
            {{#each}}
                {{!-- Make a topic list for testing --}}
                <h4>{{topic}}</h4>
            {{/each}}
        {{/with}}
    </div>
</div>
```

There's also a Faye client running, and it's subscribed to a channel that gets quite a few messages/sec. In its subscription, it calls `App.Message.addMessage(message);` and I know this is working based on the log output in addMessage. Also, I've confirmed in the Ember Inspector that the model is being updated. However, the DOM is not changing. If I switch to a different route and come back, the list shows all the items gathered while the Faye client was listening. I'm not quite sure what I should do to get the list to update dynamically.

I did notice that if I do `{{#each in content}}` or `{{#each in model.content}}` instead of the `{{#with}}` block then I get an error "Cannot set property 'dataSourceBinding' of undefined". Also, I've seen people suggest using `this.set(..., ...)` but that won't work in my case because I'd have to call it from a static context so it's undefined.

Does anyone know how to convince Ember to update the DOM in real time?

Comment: I'm also not convinced you want yo use observes instead of property, but I'm on my phone and it's a pain yo really read.

Comment: Well that's interesting - changing `getAllMessagesList`'s observes to property causes the function to not exist (there's a TypeError that you can't call undefined in the model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pushObject or addObject instead of push, it's analogous to the setter for arrays.

Since you're trying to watch the messages object, you are watching whether the reference changes, not whether or not anything under it changed.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_notifyPropertyChange

Comment: I tried both of those - changing `push(...)` to `pushObject(...)` and to `addObject(...)`, and neither had any effect.

Comment: Ahh, you're trying to watch an object, not any particular property, which means it will never recompute

Comment: You'll need to switch to an array and watch the array or manually trigger notifyPropertyChange